# red underlines in jquery in visualstudio

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2008

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        url: 'WebService.asmx/GetCustomerInformation',
        data: '{}',
        contentType: 'application/json;charset=ytf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(msg) {
            $.each(msg.d, function(i, data) {

                var name = data.Name;
                var CustomerId = data.CustomerId;
            });
        },
        Error: function() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

I get a Namespace doesn't directly contain members such as fields or methods.

```
unexpected character $.
too many character literals.
```

But I have included the library.Its not an error but the characters are underlined with red line how can it be fixed.

Comment: @minitech: I actually prefer using jsFiddle to indent (it also checks for errors, which helps while I'm fixing someone's code).

Comment: $ and the characters in red color are underlined

Comment: I'm using VS2010 and it doesn't have this problem with jQuery though in general it isn't very good at JavaScript syntax and gives green-underlined warnings about things that are perfectly valid. If a page contains some server-side code and client-side JavaScript it gets even more confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

more then likely it's because intellisense has no clue about jQuery

Comment: Visual Studio's Intellisense is not very good at JavaScript syntax in general. I'm using VS 2010 and it can't cope, so I hate to think how 2008 would go...

Comment: @nnnnnn exactly 2010 is loads better then 2k8 was... cant wait to see how it is in v.next